# Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run my app on a connected iOS device. But vscode keeps showing me **No Device**. So, I ran flutter doctor and this is what it showed me.

```
[!] Connected device
    ! Error: Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. Please check the Devices and
      Simulators Window.  (code -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with **Xcode 12.4** with **iOS 14.4.2**

Simply **Restarting The Device** solved my problem.

Comment: This was actually my problem... 1 hour of frustration solved by a simple restart. Thank you very much